# knitr/markdown: how to render math equations in vignettes built by CRAN?

Tags: rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc, mathjax

In a package, I have several vignettes that use mathematical notation, like:

```
This vignette illustrates the ideas behind solving systems of linear equations of the form $\mathbf{A x = b}$
where 

- $\mathbf{A}$ is an $m \times n$ matrix of coefficients for $m$ equations in $n$ unknowns
- $\mathbf{x}$ is an $n \times 1$ vector unknowns, $x_1, x_2, \dots x_n$
- $\mathbf{b}$ is an $m \times 1$ vector of constants, the "right-hand sides" of the equations
```

When I compile the vignette using R Studio (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>), it renders properly in the HTML file, whether viewed in the R Studio viewer or the browser.

[image]

Yet, when the package is submitted to CRAN, and the vignettes are built **there** from the source package, the math is not rendered properly, but appears as markup,

[image]

Is there something I need to add to my YAML header so that vignettes built outside of R Studio will render mathematics properly?   Currently, I use just a standard header:

```
---
title: "Solving Linear Equations"
author: "Me"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Solving Linear Equations}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---
```

The generated `pandoc` command from R Studio is

```
"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS linear-equations.utf8.md --to html --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output pandoc8141d044063.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template "C:\R\R-3.2.5\library\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html" --css "C:\R\R-3.2.5\library\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\templates\html_vignette\resources\vignette.css" --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" --highlight-style pygments
```

Perhaps I need to add a YAML option corresponding to `--self-contained` or `--standalone` ?

Comment: CRAN does not rebuild your vignettes (unless they changed it in the past few weeks), and the vignettes displayed on CRAN are just what you submitted in your source package. Please at least provide a link to the problematic vignette.

Comment: I have the same problem with `devtools::install_github(...., build_vignettes=TRUE)`. Here is the vignette: https://github.com/stla/expansions/tree/master/vignettes (cc @Yihui).

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Comment: Now they are using a different endpoint: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

Posting years later in case another user has the same question. I noticed the same issues rendering equations in my vignettes---not on CRAN, just locally hosted packages. Ctrl + Shift + K rendered fine, but viewing with `vignette()` in the RStudio Help panel renders the equations badly.

I think this is just an issue that the Help panel doesn't render the HTML completely. If I view the packaged vignette in a browser, e.g. using `RShowDoc()`, then the equations are fine. So maybe users should be directed to `RShowDoc()` more often than `vignette()`.