# knitr vignette MathJax equations not rendered

Tags: r, knitr, devtools, vignette

This is a similar question to this one which was NOT answered.

[knitr/markdown: how to render math equations in vignettes built by CRAN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39837816/knitr-markdown-how-to-render-math-equations-in-vignettes-built-by-cran)

I am developing a package for internal company use (wont be submitted to CRAN).

I have written multiple vignettes, that include some MathJAX code as well as r code.

This is their YAML:

```
---
title: "Package Title"
author: "Author"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Vignette Title}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---
```

I build the vignettes using devtools::document() and the package with "Build Binary Package".

I remove any previous versions of the package and install it again via a zip file. Everything works accordingly.

When I try vignette("package") it gives out the vignette but with mathjax rendering as strings rather than actual mathematical expressions:

[image: How it looks]

If I actually open the html files via web-browser or CTRL + Shift + K when developing them MathJax is correctly rendered, but not in the help window when you access them via vignette(…)

Any help?

Comment: I think this will be fixed in RStudio 1.2.